# Insert Binary Large Object (BLOB) in PostgreSQL using libpq from remote machine

Tags: c++, c, database, postgresql, libpq

Can you give an example of inserting binary data in PostgreSQL database from remote machine using libpq.
My second question is: Is there any other API more efficient than libpq with C++.
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 2 types of *blobs* in PostgreSQL — `BYTEA` and `Large Objects`. I'd recommend against using large objects as you can not join them to tables.

For BYTEA you'd use something like this in libpq:

```
PGresult* put_data_to_tablename(
  PGconn* conn,
  int32_t id,
  int data_size,
  const char* const data
) {
  PGresult* result;
  const uint32_t id_big_endian = htonl((uint32_t)id);
  const char* const paramValues[] = { &id_big_endian, data };
  const int nParams = sizeof(paramValues) / sizeof(paramValues[0]);
  const int paramLenghts[] = { sizeof(id_big_endian), data_size };
  const int paramFormats[] = { 1, 1 }; /* binary */
  const int resultFormat = 0; /* text */

  result = PQexecParams(
    conn,
    "insert into tablename (id, data) values ($1::integer, $2::bytea)",
    nParams,
    NULL, /* Types of parameters, unused as casts will define types */
    paramValues,
    paramLenghts,
    paramFormats,
    resultFormat
  );
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using libpqxx is the C++ way to do it, while libpq is the C API.

Here is a full example of how to do it using pqxx:  [How to insert binary data into a PostgreSQL BYTEA column using the C++ libpqxx API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047986/how-to-insert-binary-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column-using-the-c-libpqxx-a)

In short, the relevant C++ lines using libpqxx look like this:

```
void * bin_data = ...; // obviously do what you need to get the binary data...
size_t bin_size = ...; // ...and the size of the binary data
pqxx::binarystring bin( bin_data, bin_size );
pqxx::result r = work.prepared( "test" )( bin ).exec();
work.commit();
```

Comment: Worth noting there are aging issues with libpqxx, and no, it isn't the "official" postgresql c++ api as it states on the site.