# How to insert binary data into a PostgreSQL BYTEA column using the C++ libpqxx API?

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I'd like to insert some binary data into a BYTEA column, but I find the Doxygen output is lacking in details, and http://pqxx.org/ has been down for the past few days.

How would I go about inserting the contents of somefile.bin into a table with a BYTEA column?

What I have is along these lines:

```
pqxx::work work( conn );
work.exec( "CREATE TABLE test ( name varchar(20), data BYTEA )" );
work.exec( "INSERT INTO test( name, data ) VALUES ( 'foo', <insert filename.bin here> )" );
work.commit();
```

If it makes a difference, I'd like to use the new `hex` format for BYTEA available in PostgreSQL 9.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out.  Here is an example showing how to insert a bunch of binary objects into a table:

```
pqxx::connection conn( ... );
conn.prepare( "test", "INSERT INTO mytable( name, binfile ) VALUES ($1, $2)" );
pqxx::work work( conn );
for ( ... )
{
    std::string name = "foo";
    void * bin_data = ...; // obviously do what you need to get the binary data...
    size_t bin_size = 123; // ...and the size of the binary data

    pqxx::binarystring blob( bin_data, bin_size );
    pqxx::result r = work.prepared( "test" )( name )( blob ).exec();
}
work.commit();
```

Here is how to get the binary data back out of the database:

```
pqxx::result result = work.exec( "SELECT * FROM mytable" );
for ( const auto &row : result )
{
    pqxx::binarystring blob( row["binfile"] );
    void * ptr = blob.data();
    size_t len = blob.size();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but i don't like using the conn.prepare. It limits me when i have `n` element to insert with one query (performance issue). I'm working on a solution (with pqxx 5.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

There is not pqxx::bynarystring in insertion. I used the following solution to do that:

=== STORING AN wxImage IN DATABASE ====

```
//Getting image string data
wxImage foto = (...);
wxMemoryOutputStream stream;
foto.SaveFile(stream,wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
wxStreamBuffer* streamBuffer = stream.GetOutputStreamBuffer();
size_t tamanho = streamBuffer->GetBufferSize();
char* fotoData = reinterpret_cast<char*>(streamBuffer->GetBufferStart());
string dados(fotoData, tamanho);

//Performing the query
conn->prepare("InsertBinaryData", "INSERT INTO table1(bytea_field) VALUES (decode(encode($1,'HEX'),'HEX'))") ("bytea",pqxx::prepare::treat_binary);

pqxx::work w = (...);
w.prepared(dados).exec();
```

=== RETRIEVING AN wxImage FROM DATABASE ====

```
pqxx::result r = w.exec("SELECT bytea_field FROM table1 WHERE (...)");
w.commit();

const result::tuple row = r[0];
const result::field tfoto = row[0];

pqxx::binarystring bs(tfoto);
const char* dadosImg = bs.get();
size_t size = bs.length();

wxMemoryInputStream stream(dadosImg,size);
wxImage imagem;

imagem.LoadFile(stream);
```

I hope it be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using prepared SQL statement with `conn.prepare` as in Stéphane's answer if you want you can simply escape the binary data with one of overloads of `pqxx::escape_binary` function. [Here](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00203.html) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is the top search result for inserting a BYTEA via libpqxx, here's another way to do it using a parameterized query, which is more appropriate if performing a single insert.

```
// Assuming pre-existing pqxx::connection c, void * bin_data, size_t bin_size...
pqxx::work txn(c);
pqxx::result res = txn.parameterized("INSERT INTO mytable(name, binfile) VALUES ($1, $2)")
                                    (name)
                                    (pqxx::binarystring(bin_data, bin_size))
                                    .exec();
txn.commit();
```

Note that the parameters should *not* be escaped with the `quote` or `esc` methods.

Also note that the accepted answer of using `pqxx::connection::prepare` causes the prepared query to exist for the entire lifetime of the connection. If the connection will be long-lasting and the prepared query is no longer needed, it should probably be deleted by calling `pqxx::connection::unprepare`.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a flexible solution using binary data inside `std::string`.

I propose this new solution because current answers are old (2013) and I was looking for a multi insert query using pqxx 5.0.1.

With the solution bellow you have the flexibility to use a `for loop` to append multiple binary data in a single insert query.

```
CustomStruct data = .... ; // have some binary data

// initialise connection and declare worker
pqxx::connection conn = new pqxx::connection(...);    
pqxx::work w(conn); 

// prepare query
string query += "INSERT INTO table (bytea_field) VALUES ("
// convert your data in a binary string. 
pqxx::binarystring blob((void *)&(data), data.size());
// avoid null character to bug your query string. 
query += "'"+w.esc_raw(blob.str())+"');";

//execute query
pqxx::result rows = w.exec(query);
```

When we want to retrieve data from the database you should have the scope of your datatype (`CustomStruct` for instance) and you should be able to cast it back in the binary format of your choice.

```
// assuming worker and connection are declared and initialized.
string query = "SELECT bytea_field FROM table;";
pqxx::result rows = w.exec(query);
for(pqxx::result::iterator col = rows.begin(); col != rows.end(); ++col)
{
    pqxx::binarystring blob(col[0]);
    CustomStruct *data = (CustomStruct*) blob.data();
    ...
}
```

This was tested with `pqxx 5.0.1`, `c++11` and `postgresSQL 9.5.8`