# How to write array[] bytea using libpq PQexecParams?

Tags: postgresql, libpq, bytea

I need help with write array[] bytea using libpq PQexecParams

I'v done a simple version where i'm write a single binary data in a single bytea arg using PQexecParams like this solution [Insert Binary Large Object (BLOB) in PostgreSQL using libpq from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994702/insert-binary-large-object-blob-in-postgresql-using-libpq-from-remote-machine)

But I have problems with write array[] bytea like this

> select * func(array[3, 4], array[bytea, bytea])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert Binary Large Object (BLOB) in PostgreSQL using libpq from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994702/insert-binary-large-object-blob-in-postgresql-using-libpq-from-remote-machine)

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @PavelKorotkevich No, this is insert single blob. API in database with i work requeired array[bytea, bytea...] array[int,int ...] etc

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't understand how to make correct params for function PQexecParams. With single object that what easy and work fine

Comment: A `bytea` is just a single object. It is no different than other data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Edited the question for some details

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to read the PostgreSQL source to figure out the binary format for arrays, you will have to use the text format, e.g.

```
{\\xDEADBEEF,\\x00010203}
```

The binary format for arrays is defined in `array_send` in `src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c`. Have a look at the somments and definitions in `src/include/utils/array.h` as well. Consider also that all integers are sent in “network bit order”.

One way you can examine the binary output format and saving yourself a lot of trouble experimenting is to use binary copy, e.g.

```
COPY (SELECT ARRAY['\xDEADBEEF'::bytea,'\x00010203'::bytea])
   TO '/tmp/file' (FORMAT 'binary');
```

Comment: I thied this, but libpq reject my query with different reason -> invalid utf-8, slashed, quotes, null symbol etc. hex work, but convert string to \ from hex representation symbol by symbol is slow. Some more info my binary string  is a protobuf serialization result.. Maybe has a good variant for escaping this? Pgescaping is not a good choice, but my variants was rejected by libpq

Comment: I forgot to escape the backslashes, and I have added some pointers to the source.

Comment: escape the backslashes is not a big problem, i already write that tried to use different way(escaping, hex, base64, E\, $$ tokens erc). PQExec work only with text format - it not good for me. I want send my data with native bytes... gone to read libpq sources :(

Comment: You don't need libpq sources, you need PostgreSQL server sources, as indicated in my answer.